# How to customize a GKMatchmakerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I want to create a custom `GKMatchMakerViewController`

Code with the standard `ViewController` (colorful bubbles):

```
 if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated){
        GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] ;
        request.minPlayers = 2;
        request.maxPlayers = 2;
        GKMatchmakerViewController *MM = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
        MM.matchmakerDelegate = self;
     [self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom view controller from scratch. Then you load your matches using `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:` method. Then you can present your matches on your controller, for example using a `UITableView`. See [GKTurnBasedMatch Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKTurnBasedMatch/loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Change MM (in 2 places) to mmvc 
Or change mmvc (in one place) to MM